# Extracting values from Windows registry

Tags: windows, batch-file, registry

Trying to write a windows cmd script to replicate the functionality of a linux shell script.  In linux it is almost trivial because all of the source data needed is in text files, but in Windows I need to get it from the registry.

Given an input string of, say 'xxxx', I am looking for key hklm\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\OracleServiceXXXX. Under that key is a string named 'ImagePath', with a value of '\bin\ORACLE.EXE XXXX'

I need to get that 'somestring' into a script variable for further use.

Solution needs to be in a .cmd script - no dependency on extra component installations like java, perl, etc.  I'd guess PoweShell would be acceptable.  I just need to be sure I could drop the script onto any Windows server machine and know that the dependencies are there.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
@set /p INPUT="Which string?"
reg query "HKLM\CurrentControlSet\Services\OracleService%INPUT%" /v ImagePath
```

?

Comment: very close.  I expanded that out to `for /f "tokens=3" %%i in ('reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\OracleService%INPUT%" /v ImagePath') do set ORACLE_HOME=%%i`.  That results in a string like `c:\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\bin\ORACLE.EXE`.  Now I just need to strip off the `\bin\ORACLE.EXE`, keeping just the `c:\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1`. The `\bin` is the known constant.  I played around with the `delim` keyword, but couldn't seem to find the right combination.